# DSN-less ODBC Access-VBA

Tags: ms-access, odbc, vba, dsn

(between Sage Line 100 and MS Access)

I am trying to foolproof the import of a table into MS Access from Sage Line 100. 
Since several tables from several sources have to be imported and queries to be run in a specific order, I want to automate this with a one-click (form button which will run a macro to import dbases run queries and export)

There are several source locations from where to import the tables and not all users have the system DSNs set (nor do i want to go around setting them for everyone - I am not the IT guy (there is no IT guy)).

This is the code I am trying:

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC Database", _<br>
    "ODBC;DRIVER={SAGE Line 100}; LOG=S:\apps\L100;" & _ 
    "SCH=S:\apps\svnp;DIR=S:\data\svnd\mfg;" & _
    "UID=abcd;PWD=defg;LANGUAGE=us_english;" & _
    "DATABASE=ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.STOCK_CONTROL_FILE", _
    acTable, "ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.STOCK_CONTROL_FILE", "ASSCF"
```

The above leads to :

[image: First Window]

On clicking 'OK' :

[image: Error Window]

Same result from:

```
Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO ASSCF" & _
             " FROM [ODBC;DRIVER={SAGE Line 100};" & _
             "LOG=S:\apps\L100;SCH=S:\apps\svnp;DIR=S:\data\svnd\mfg;" & _
             " UID=ajay;PWD=ajoo].ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.STOCK_CONTROL_FILE;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Note:

I can successfully import data when I use the DSNs I set up on my system:

```
Dim strSQL As String
    strSQL = "SELECT * INTO ASSCF" & _
             " FROM [ODBC;DSN=SAGE-mfg" & _
             " UID=ajay;PWD=ajoo].ACCOUNTING_SYSTEM.STOCK_CONTROL_FILE;"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Not an answer, but these comments may be of interest http://andrewonedegree.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/sage-line-100-odbc-driver-hmmm/#comments

Answer (score 0):

Instead of embedding the DRIVER in your sql statement, why don't you set up an odbc connection string and then open the connection via the connection string and execute the sql. I think the "ODBC" in front of the "DRIVER" in your sql statment is causing the error.